# Does SQL Server 2014 have a feature like Oracle Multitenant databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, oracle-12c, multi-tenant

In Oracle 12c, a feature called [Multitenant databases](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/options.htm#DBLIC2166) is available. This way you can have two seemingly separate databases installed on one system, yet be able to manage Backups and Resource Management for one "Container Database".

Does SQL Server have a similar feature?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is [contained databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929071.aspx) as of SQL Server 2012

> A contained database is a database that is isolated from other
>   databases and from the instance of SQL Server that hosts the database.
>   SQL Server 2016 helps user to isolate their database from the instance
>   in 4 ways.

- Much of the metadata that describes a database is maintained in the database. (In addition to, or instead of, maintaining metadata in the master database.)
- All metadata are defined using the same collation.
- User authentication can be performed by the database, reducing the databases  dependency on the logins of the instance of SQL Server.
- The SQL Server environment (DMV's, XEvents, etc.) reports and can act upon containment information.

For what I've done with contained databases so far, its been useful for isolating user authentication.

Comment: Cool. Surprising they don't mention this anywhere in the datasheet. Would you happen to know if this is included in the Standard edition? I can't find any information on it... Datasheet:http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/A/2/8A2BC8C5-BBA0-4A9C-90BC-AC957D3454D9/SQL_Server_2016_Editions_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Hi @Wouter, yes it is supported in standard and apparently all edtions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx. Its listed under security features

Comment: Thanks so much for digging this up. Googling didn't make me find this...

Comment: After installing, and testing, I've figuered out that it doesn't support Resource Management as Oracle Multitenant databases do. "Resource Governor" as it is called in MSSQL, can only be used -within- one instance. A "contained database" is pretty much the same as what a schema in oracle is. So, this is not what I was looking for, sorry.

Comment: To be more specific, in an oracle multitentant environment, you have one Container database, and multiple Pluggable databases. Each database (called an instance in the MSSQL world) can have multiple schema's (called a database in the MSSQL world). A propper MSSQL equivalent would be installing multiple MSSQL instances, and still being able to do resource management amongst them, not just inside them.